# main method in intellij worksheet doesn't run?

Tags: scala

I am trying to use the worksheet functionality of Intellij. I have this simple code:

```
object Timer {

    // this function takes another function as an argument.
    // that function takes no args, and doesn't return anything.
    def oncePerSecond(callback: () => Unit) {
        while (true) { callback(); Thread.sleep(1000) }
    }

    // the function we'll pass in to oncePerSecond.
    // this can be any function that takes no args and doesn't
    // return anything.
    def timeFlies() {
        println("time flies like an arrow ...")
    }

    // the main() method, where we pass timeFlies into oncePerSecond.
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        oncePerSecond(timeFlies)
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it run? I don't see "time flies like an arrow" when it executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run this method inside worksheet you shouldn't put it in main method but:

```
oncePerSecond(timeFlies)
```

without anything. In this Timer object.

Edit:
If you want to run it from a console you can use scalac and scala:

```
scalac Timer.scala
scala Timer
```

Or you can create a simple sbt project or use another build tool.

Edit2: Previously I didn't see that you have one more question. Your code doesn't work because in practice you create a method main without using it. In a worksheet, you need to use a method to see the result. So if you put in object:

```
val a = 1
```

and you run this worksheet you can see that it's evaluated on the right side (in the right window).
The same situation is with a method. If you create some method you can see that method is created. To see the result you only need to use this method and run the worksheet.